# Issue with getting values from JSON array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am returning two objects using json_encode from a PHP file using jQuery/AJAX. The response looks like this:

```
{"result":{"trueresults":[["April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm","8734hjgfd784ew"],["April 12th 2017, 4:53:57 pm","8734hjgfd784ew"]],"falseresults":[["April 12th 2017, 1:07:03 pm","8734hjgfd784ew"],["April 12th 2017, 4:56:17 pm","8734hjgfd784ew"]]},"errors":false}

{"result":{"trueresults":[["April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm","17x1p14e6662"],["April 12th 2017, 1:05:54 pm","17x1p14e6662"]],"falseresults":[["April 12th 2017, 1:05:53 pm","17x1p14e6662"],["April 12th 2017, 1:05:55 pm","17x1p14e6662"]]},"errors":false}
```

I am then looping through the results and doing some date-time calculations like this:

```
.success(function(response) {
    if(!response.errors && response.result) {
        var trueresultgroup = response.result.trueresults;
        var falseresultgroup = response.result.falseresults;
        var tot = moment.duration(0);
            for (i = 0; i < trueresultgroup.length; i++) {                  
              var on = (trueresultgroup[i]).toString();
              var off = (falseresultgroup[i]).toString();
              var ms = moment(off,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a").diff(moment(on,"MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
              tot.add(ms, 'ms');                  
              var dtime = moment.duration(tot).asHours();
            }
            var s = tot.format("hh [hours] :mm [minutes] :ss [seconds]");
            $("#divtimes").append('<p>'+s+'</p>');

    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

How can I access the second values in the array? I can access the "April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm" part from `["April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm","8734hjgfd784ew"]`, how can I access the "8734hjgfd784ew" ?

To clarify, I am calculating the times a device has been on using the dates. I am able to do this but I would like to add the devicename (8734hjgfd784ew etc) and then the result next to it, but I don't know how to access that part in the response.

Comment: your for loop need to change the condition try for (i = 0; i <= trueresultgroup.length; i++){}... you must use greater than equal operator to reach the length of your array

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Adhan. I am very new to coding. Could you please explain?

Comment: Try `trueresultgroup[i][0].toString()` for `April 12th 2017, 1:05:52 pm` and `trueresultgroup[i][1].toString()` for `8734hjgfd784ew`

Comment: Thanks Antonis, that worked perfectly. I understand the logic I need to use in future. Thanks :)